# Python how to convert monthly employment data into annual, csv, panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rsample

I've been stuck on this problem for two days. Below is the csv file.

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('/14100017.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
df_year = df.groupby('REF_DATE')['REF_DATE'].count()
print(df_year)
```

This is my code. Could you please tell me or give me a hint or show me the website has similar questions. How to convert monthly employment data into annual by taking average? This is so confused.

Thank you very much! Much appreciated

I tried search similar questions in reddit forum and Stack overflow, they all used rsample and get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert REF_DATE to *datetime* and then extract year:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REF_DATE'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
```

After, you need to aggregate the value by year:

```
monthly_year_avg = df.groupby('year')['VALUE'].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After your code, I use.   print(df_year/12), but it shows same valuesREF_DATE
1976-01    605.0
1976-02    605.0
1976-03    605.0
1976-04    605.0
1976-05    605.0

Comment: Do you mean that terget col is the VALUE col?

Comment: yes, thank you again! My target is to covert the monthly data into annually by taking average which is divided 12.

Comment: I've editted my answer to match your expectations